# remove price text from custom option from cart page

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.3.8, I need some customization in custom options text in cart page.

I want to remove custom option price from cart page.

[image]

I want to just hide euro 23.99 and euro 12.00 from those custom options no any other effects I want.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: which theme or template you are using ?As in default rwd magento theme custom option prices are not displayed in cart page.

Comment: i got answer from the same question which was asked in stack magento exchange https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233200/remove-price-text-from-custom-option-from-cart-page?noredirect=1#comment329163_233200

Answer (score 1):

As your theme is not default magento's theme you should look for it's possible config field. 
If there isn't any config It can be hidden by CSS simply.
If you give your website's URL I can check it out for you.
cheers :)